# Getting syntax error on Mono.onErrorResume() while using a HttpGraphQLClient

Tags: spring-boot, maven, client, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I am using java 17, spring-boot: 3.0.5 and maven in my project. I am calling a GraphQL endpoint using HttpGraphQlClient. Below is my expected code snippet:

```
Mono<Entity> entity = this.graphQlClient.documentName("getDetails").variables(Map.of("xx", "xx"))
                        .retrieve("data")
                        .toEntity(Entity.class)
                        .onErrorResume(FieldAccessException.class, ex -> {
                        ClientGraphQlResponse response = ex.getResponse();
            // ...
            ClientResponseField field = ex.getField();
            // ...
                        });
```

However, I am getting syntax error at `onErrorResume(....)`. Below is the error I am getting:

**Cannot resolve method 'onErrorResume(Class, )'**

Below are the suggestions I get:

Candidates for method call
this.graphQlClient.documentName("getDetails").variables(Map.of("xx", "xx")) .retrieve("data") .toEntity(Entity.class).onErrorResume(FieldAccessException.class, ex -> { }) are:

- Mono onErrorResume(Function<? super Throwable, ? extends Mono<? extends TransactionEntity>>)
- Mono onErrorResume(Class, Function<? super FieldAccessException, ? extends Mono<? extends TransactionEntity>>)
- Mono onErrorResume(Predicate<? super Throwable>, Function<? super Throwable, ? extends Mono<? extends TransactionEntity>>)

Spring documention has the same code block given as example: [Spring-graphql-retrieve-method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html#client.requests.retrieve)

I would like to know how to fix this error? How to handle error using retrieve method ?

I want to handle error thrown from graphQL endpoint in an effective manner. Eventhough, we can use .execute() method to have more control on the GraphQL response, I wanted to use .retrieve() since it is provided in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onErrorResume` operator means that you will handle errors of a certain type and provide a fallback ([see the Javadoc here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-)).

In your case you should return a fallback value of type `Entity`.

```
Mono<Entity> entity = this.graphQlClient.documentName("getDetails")
        .variables(Map.of("xx", "xx"))
        .retrieve("data")
        .toEntity(Entity.class)
        .onErrorResume(FieldAccessException.class, ex -> {
            return Mono.just(new Entity("defaultValue"));
        });
```

You are getting a compiler error because the compiler expects `onErrorResume` to return a type `Mono<Entity>`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. This helped.

Comment: Could you also help me understand, which method I should use incase I want to throw an exception on error  instead of fallback?

Comment: could you please address my above query. @Brian

Comment: it's hard to anwser to new questions in comments. Without knowing more about your context, maybe calling `.block()` to return directly an `Entity` would work.